# Which @GenricGenrator can be used instead of sequence to start from 1?

Tags: java

which strategy we can use in GenricGenrator to start the sequence from 1 because using a sequence as a strategy it starts from the previous table ending?

Comment: What is a `GenricGenrator`? Are you talking about Hibernate?

Comment: And what is "the previous table ending"? A hibernate sequence generator starts from the next value of the sequence.

Comment: Yes, @luk2302 I am talking about hibernate . And the previous table ending means the sequence generates value like this first it will generate for the first table than in the continuation, it is generating for the second. Not from the 1.